# The method '_PayWallWidgetState' isn't defined for the type 'PayWallWidget'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to make an Paywallwidget but when i want to make the paywallwidget state i get this error: The method '_PayWallWidgetState' isn't defined for the type 'PayWallWidget'. What am i doing wrong here?

```
import 'package:glassfy_flutter/models.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class PayWallWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final GlassfyOffering offer;
  final ValueChanged<GlassfySku> onClickedSku;

  const PayWallWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.offer,
    required this.onClickedSku,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PayWallWidget> createState() => _PayWallWidgetState();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```dart
class PayWallWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PayWallWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.offer,
    required this.onClickedSku,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String description;
  final GlassfyOffering offer;
  final ValueChanged<GlassfySku> onClickedSku;

  @override
  State<PayWallWidget> createState() => _PayWallWidgetState();
}

class _PayWallWidgetState extends State<PayWallWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return …;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have nothing for in the build widget. What do i have to do now?

Comment: @Android_devNL So why did you create this `StatefulWidget`? What exactly are you trying to do?